# MYSQL:[Note] InnoDB: page_cleaner: 1000ms intended loop took 4303ms. The settings might not be optimal. (flushed=396 and evicted=0, during the time.)

Tags: mysql

In  MySQL5.7.11,the error log display the

> "[Note] InnoDB: page_cleaner: 1000ms intended loop took 4303ms. The
>   settings might not be optimal. (flushed=396 and evicted=0, during the
>   time.)"

frequently,and I set the  parameter `innodb_page_cleaners=8` and `innodb_buffer_pool_instances=8` and reboot the MYSQL service,but the error also show frequently,what should I do ?
Please help me!Thanks a lot!

Comment: When this happens (so the 4s before the message appears), is there some CPU or IO spike maybe? Is your server doing a lot of work? Do you use HDD or SSD storage?

Comment: yes,the CPU and IO is high,the mysql5.7.11 is the slave of mysql5.6.21,the slave is doing replications,I use the general HDD.

Comment: You might want to have a look at the following Q&A over on Stackoverflow: [How to solve mysql warning: “InnoDB: page_cleaner: 1000ms intended loop took XXX ms. The settings might not be optimal”?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41134785/1820861).