# InnoDB page_cleaner error message: The settings might not be optimal

Tags: innodb, mysql-5.7

My server is in idle state but I often get this error:

> ```
> Note: InnoDB: page_cleaner: 1000ms intended loop took 35165ms. 
> The settings might not be optimal. 
> flushed=0 and evicted=0, during the time
> ```

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: You might want to have a look at the following Q&A over on Stackoverflow: [How to solve mysql warning: “InnoDB: page_cleaner: 1000ms intended loop took XXX ms. The settings might not be optimal”?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41134785/1820861) or the same question on DBA.SE which sadly hasn't received an answer yet: [MYSQL:Note InnoDB: page_cleaner: 1000ms intended loop took 4303ms. The settings might not be optimal. (flushed=396 and evicted=0, during the time.)](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/138701/15356)

Comment: It might also be related to the following bug report in the MySQL Bugs section: [Improve help when reporting page cleaner loop taking too long](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=76661).

Answer (score -2):

```
mysql> set global innodb_lru_scan_depth=256;
```